# How to populate a Spark DataFrame column based on another column's value?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, anonymous-function

I have a use-case where I need to select certain columns from a `dataframe` containing atleast 30 columns and millions of rows.

I'm loading this data from a `cassandra` table using `scala` and `apache-spark`.

I selected the required columns using: `df.select("col1","col2","col3","col4")`

Now I have to perform a basic `groupBy` operation to group the data according to `src_ip`,`src_port`,`dst_ip`,`dst_port` and I also want to have the latest value from a `received_time` column of the original `dataframe`.
[image: Original DataFrame]

I want a `dataframe` with `distinct` `src_ip` values with their `count` and latest `received_time` in a new column as `last_seen`.

I know how to use `.withColumn` and also, I think that `.map()` can be used here.
Since I'm relatively new in this field, I really don't know how to proceed further. I could really use your help to get done with this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe df with `src_ip,src_port,dst_ip,dst_port and received_time`, you can try:

```scala
val mydf = df.groupBy(col("src_ip"),col("src_port"),col("dst_ip"),col("dst_port")).agg(count("received_time").as("row_count"),max(col("received_time")).as("max_received_time"))
```

The above line calculates the count of timestamp received against the group by columns as well as the max timestamp for that group by columns.